# Flex/ActionScript - XML 

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex, object

I am trying to read the below xml file and get the name-value pairs in Flex / Actionscript.

**Sample.xml**

```
<ABC>
  <XYZ>               // First child
    <id> </id>
    <width> 10 </width>
    <height> 10 </height>
    <name> Person1 </name>
  </XYZ>
  <XYZ>              // Second child
    <id>  </id>
    <width>  20 </width>
    <height> 20 </height>
    <name> Person2 </name>
   </XYZ>
</ABC>
```

I am trying to use the following all tag name and value details for both childs using `.name()` and `.text()` function of XML

But I am not getting it.

My question is,

> Can anyone please tell me how to parse this xml to obtain the details
>   of each child separately in an object and then store that object in
>   array for later use ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just keep it in XML and use it as the source for an XMLListCollection? E4x syntax isn't that much different than object reference syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var xml:XML =
            <ABC>
                <XYZ>               // First child
                    <id> </id>
                    <width> 10 </width>
                    <height> 10 </height>
                    <name> Person1 </name>
                </XYZ>
                <XYZ>
                    <id>  </id>
                    <width>  20 </width>
                    <height> 20 </height>
                    <name> Person2 </name>
                </XYZ>
            </ABC>;
        // Get list of children named XYZ
        var children:XMLList = xml.XYZ;
        for each (var child:XML in children)
        {
            trace(child.name());
            // Get list of inner children (with any name)
            for each (var prop:XML in child.children())
            {
                // You need text from inner children, so here it is
                trace("\t" + prop.name() + " = " + prop.text());
            }
        }
```

Note that your comment (// First child) will become text node with null name in child list.
Comments in XML are like this:
`<!-- comment -->`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`e4x`](http://www.nbilyk.com/e4x-example) which is ECMAScript for XML. e4x, much like XPath, can traverse through the XML document to find elements.

**Here are some articles by Adobe.**

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/E4X
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_03.html

**Look at the samples in the following document.**

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html

**Some tutorials**

[Look here for a tutorial](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/E4X/)
[Here's another tutorial](http://www.nbilyk.com/e4x-example)

Comment: Some people feel that answers that are mainly links are poo.  I am not one of those people, but I have had my answer downgraded to a comment because of this before.