# Store name-value pair in flex/actionscript

Tags: xml, arrays, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

In reference to this question,

[Flex/ActionScript - XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032697/parse-xml-to-get-name-and-value-of-tags-in-flex)

I am able to get the name and value pairs of the `<id>`,`<width>` etc XML tags.

But I am not able to store them as a name-value pair in Array/ArrayCollection, 
i.e

```
id - ""  
width - 10  
height - 10  
name - Person1
```

I want to use them later in my application. How to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A basic implementation of key-value pairs in AS is [Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) or [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html).